# Multiple displays won't work under 19.10on HP x360?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hp, hdmi

This may be straightforward, but I can't get it to work.

I am running 19.10 on an HP X360 with Gnome.

I want to connect it to an external display, but for some reason Settings won't allow me to do it. I don't have an "Activities" header in my window bar, just "Applications" and "Places". How do I connect a further display to it?

The S/w is a clone (pretty much) of the set up on my previous HP Pavilion,also running 19.10,  which drives a secondary display just fine.

Any suggestions,

Thanks

PS. I have tried connecting via an HDMI to my TV in the hope that something would be automatically enabled to allow me to drive it, but no luck.

Comment: BY way of additional info if I plug the older machine into an HDMI line, to the TV 19.10 just detects it automatically, picks up my laptop screen and we're away! Tried it a couple of hours ago,